# How to use previously defined Pandas dataframe in AzureML web service?

Tags: python, pandas, web-services, azure

I would like to deploy an AzureML web service via a Jupyter notebook on AzureML Studio using a Python2.7 kernel. This web service will be using (in addition to a trained ML model) a previously defined Pandas dataframe.

Now, as I understand from [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python#publishing), any global variables referred to by the published function will be serialized using Pickle so they can be used when the web service is consumed. Indeed, if I publish a web service that makes use of a previously defined integer, function, or numpy array I can [consume](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/studio/consume-web-services.md#python-sample) the web service without a problem:

```
from azureml import services
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

#Define some function...
def square(n):
    return n*n

#... and some variables we might want to use in the web service below
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)))
x = df.values

#Create the web service
@services.publish(workspace_id, authorization_token)
@services.types(number=int)
@services.returns(int)

def my_published_func(number):
    tmp = sum(sum(x == number))
    return square(tmp)
```

However, as soon as I try to use the dataframe `df` inside `my_published_func` (e.g. when replacing `x == number` with `df.values == number`), a call to the web service gives the following error (which seems to indicate some serializing-related issue):

> {u'error': {u'message': u'Module execution encountered an error.',
>   u'code': u'ModuleExecutionError', u'details': [{u'message': u'Error
>   0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please
>   view the output log for more information:\r\n---------- Start of error
>   message from Python interpreter ----------\r\nCaught exception while
>   executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   "\server\InvokePy.py", line 118, in executeScript\n    mod =
>   safe_module_import(script)\n  File "\server\InvokePy.py", line 79,
>   in safe_module_import\n    return import_module(h)\n  File
>   "C:\pyhome\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module\n
>   **import**(name)\n  File "\temp\1263948264.py", line 1124, in \n    __user_function =
>   _deserialize_func(base64.decodestring(\'*long string of gibberish goes here*'), globals())\n  File "\temp\1263948264.py", line 1101,
>   in _deserialize_func\n    codeArgs, funcArgs, updatedGlobals =
>   pickle.loads(data)\nImportError: No module named
>   indexes.base\n\r\n\r\n---------- End of error message from Python 
>   interpreter  ----------', u'code': u'85', u'target': u'Execute Python
>   Script RRS'}]}}

Does this mean that global variables referring to Pandas dataframes (even though these can be [pickled](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)) cannot be used inside an AzureML web service, or is there a way to make this work?